# Hadoop sample job failing with Exception from container-launch

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a cluster setup with 2 nodes and I am trying the wordcount sample. When I send out the job and monitor it on my ResourceManager web GUI, I got this exception

```
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1425407150767_0009_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I check my logs on the web GUI, I see this

```
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What does this mean? I have my JAVA_HOME and everything set correctly, I'm not sure whats causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It Mean your Java Configuration is not correct (in path).

Check you **JAVA_HOME**, it should point to

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

and path should be like `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

you need to keep executable path in PATH variable but not the base HOME dir.

hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same trouble, and I have fixed it.

1. Avoid using java from c:\program files

Copy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75 to **C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75**, in order to skip the 'space' on 'Program Files' and set JAVA_HOME  to C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

2. Check the quote of JAVA_HOME

Check your JAVA_HOME at hadoop-env.cmd that

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75
```

not

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75"
```

In other words, " " is not work on Windows parameter.